# MySQL order by(`field`, param1, param2, param3 from JSON array

Tags: mysql, json, sorting, field

I'm building Mysql query:

```
select * from `table` order by field(`column`, "param1", "param2", "param3")
```

where param1, param2, param3 comes from JSON Array ["param1", "param2", "param3"]
and when I put the parameters hardcoded in the query everything is OK, but when I prepare it (because I don't know what count and order is coming):

```
set json_array='["param1", "param2", "param3"]';
select * from `table` order by field(`column`, replace(replace(json_array, '[', ''), ']', ''))
```

Its not working.

Comment: This is going to be a tough one to answer. You may want to reference where you found your original documentation on how to do this, even if its not complete enough.  I've googled it and not found anything directly related.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

```
SET @json_array='["param3", "param1", "param2"]';
SET @query = CONCAT('select * from `table` order by field(`column`, ',
                    replace(replace(@param, '[', ''), ']', ')'));
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pZGZrgMH4R6kSrbsweSVT4/1)

Comment: For me it doesn't work - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c738f/1 :-(

Comment: @iMarh I have found a solution for MySQL 5.7. Which version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: My version is 5.5. I see that 5.5 also works. Thanks Alberto!

Comment: @iMarh Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)